# Prometheus scraping target with login and password

Tags: configuration, yaml, prometheus, monitoring

- I have an exporter in your prometheus in the target 10.10.1.2
- the metric_path is : /test/metrics/cpu
- the scheme is https
- The target has login and password

How to configure login and password related to the target in prometheus.yml file. Since the basic_auth is described in the documentation as for Prometheus authentication not the target itself. And when I try the basic_auth I have the error INVALID is not a valid token :

```
 scrape_configs:
 - job_name: 'exporter_test'
   metrics_path: '/test/metrics/cpu'
   scheme: 'https'
   static_configs:
      - targets: ['10.10.1.2']
    basic_auth:
      username: 'target_login'
      password: 'pass_target'
```

Thank you

Comment: The configuration you show in your question is the correct configuration to configure Prometheus to scrape a target using HTTP basic auth. The error may be an error in the result of the scrape. Can you e.g. curl the endpoint yourself and receive metrics? `curl --user target_login:pass_target https://10.10.1.2/test/metrics/cpu`?